# GWT in Eclipse - Error loading Modules

Tags: java, gwt, module, enums

I have a java application that I made and this week I tried to add GWT to it.
I get this error when trying to see my class in GWT Designer:

```
Error loading module(s).

GWT Designer can't load a module because of error in gwt.xml module description, incorrect resource which requires processing with GWT generator or by some other configuration error.

Please check your $project_dir/.gwt/.gwt-log for GWT-specific errors (not GWT Designer errors).

This log has the following error messages:



   [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/Temp/essd/Projecto/anacom/src/main/java/anacom/shared/dto/OutputObterModoDto.java'

      [ERROR] Line 8: No source code is available for type anacom.domain.Modo; did you forget to inherit a required module?

   [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/Temp/essd/Projecto/anacom/src/main/java/anacom/shared/dto/TelemovelDetalhadoDto.java'

      [ERROR] Line 8: No source code is available for type anacom.domain.Modo; did you forget to inherit a required module?

   [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/Temp/essd/Projecto/anacom/src/main/java/anacom/shared/exception/TelemovelModoException.java'

      [ERROR] Line 17: No source code is available for type anacom.domain.Modo; did you forget to inherit a required module?

   [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/Temp/essd/Projecto/anacom/src/main/java/anacom/shared/dto/OutputObterModoDto.java'

      [ERROR] Line 8: No source code is available for type anacom.domain.Modo; did you forget to inherit a required module?

   [ERROR] Unable to find type 'anacom.presentationserver.client.AnacomGWT'

      [ERROR] Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable

      [ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly
```

All the files that have that error have the import of the class anacom.domain.Modo. That class is an enum, that only contains this:

```
package anacom.domain;

public enum Modo {
    LIGADO, DESLIGADO, OCUPADO, SILENCIO
}
```

Also, in the gwt.xml I inherit the module and define the entrypoint class.
I've spent the last three days trying to work this out. If you could help me I would appreciate. Sorry if this is a newbie question but in my search through the web I have not found a solution. Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you using `anacom.domain.Modo` on the client or server? If on the client, you need the source code, not just the class files.

Comment: @TravisWebb I'm using on both and by class I meant that I have the java files. Were you refering to that?

Comment: I edited my answer. May be the first item will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/18009856/2607703

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I managed to find a solution. Not what I expected but it solves this.

I moved the enum class to another package; the DTOs and the exceptions are under the package shared and then in their respective folders. I created, under shared, a domain folder. Then I altered my dml and all of my other classes (and believe me, it's a big project with local and remote running) so that the enum referred would be this one.

So I guess the solution with enums and DTOs is having the same package. I also included the domain folder on the modules file.

Thank you all for trying to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some possiblities of the problem.

1. Make sure that you have placed your gwt.xml file under anacom package. i.e anacom/gwt.xml
2. you have added `<source path="domain">` in gwt.xml
3. Make your enum Serializable i.e

   public enum Modo implements Serializable  {

   LIGADO, DESLIGADO, OCUPADO, SILENCIO

   }

Or

```
public enum Modo implements IsSerializable {
    LIGADO, DESLIGADO, OCUPADO, SILENCIO
    }
```

4) Genrate a default constructor i.e

```
public Modo () {
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, tried all of them but unfortunately the problem remained :(

Comment: Had the issue just added the new package to the source setting in gwt.xml and voilà!

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Be sure that the project contains package anacom.domain.Modo must have a gwt.xml file and You should reference it from your startup project

### 2. Be sure that client side does not reference any object type in the server-side packages

You know that gwt apps consist of two or three main sections which are client,server and shared packages. Usually client apps doesn't reference types in server packages to accordance with the principles of design. You may consider this detail, too.

For this sample, type "anacom.domain.Modo" seems as in a server-side package.